# php implode breaks on spaces

Tags: php, implode

I have an array of strings, and these strings have spaces in them. For example:

```
$arr = array('bob', 'john smith', 'grease monkey', 'etc');
```

Why is it when I try to `$str = implode('|', $arr);`, it stops at the first space it finds??
I'm left with a string like:

```
$str = "bob|john";
```

If I try:

```
$arr = array('bob', 'john', 'grease monkey', 'etc');
```

and implode, I get:

```
$str = "bob|john|grease";
```

**Edit:** I'm actually trying to set it to the value of a hidden field:

```
<input id="hidLblFields" name="hidLblFields" type="text" value=<?php echo implode('|', $myFields);?> />
```

Comment: You're assigning an array to `$str`, not `$arr`. I assume that was a typo in the question. Anyway, with that fixed, I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: That isn't how implode works. Show us some more code around the same area you are using implode.

Comment: @icktoofay yes, it was a typo

Comment: Maybe another typo, but use quotes around value `value="<?php echo implode('|', $myFields);?>"`, otherwise the space of course breaks the html

Comment: @Nicklamort I still see no quotes around input value

Comment: @Damien Thank you, that was my problem ><

Comment: Damn. next time I should write an answer not a comment LOL glad to have helped

Comment: @Damien write it, I'll give you the answer

Comment: No problem, my fault ;) Go mark the one you feel most appropriate among those given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Edit: I'm actually trying to set it to the value of a hidden field:
>
> ```
> <input id="hidLblFields" name="hidLblFields" type="text" value=<?php echo implode('|', $myFields);?> />
> ```

You need to quote the `value` attribute:

```
<input .. type="text" value="<?php echo implode('|', $myFields);?>" />
```

Without doing that, the rendered HTML looks like:

```
<input type="text" value=bob|john|grease monkey />
```

Which the browser will handle as this:

```
<input type="text" value="bob|john|grease" monkey />
```

Answer (score 2):

You must have an error somewhere else in your code, implode() does not break on spaces.

```
$arr = array('bob', 'john', 'grease monkey', 'etc');
$str = implode('|', $arr);
var_dump($str);
// gives
string(26) "bob|john|grease monkey|etc"
```

As for your edit, you need quotes around attributes in html:

```
<input id="hidLblFields" name="hidLblFields" type="text" value="<?php echo implode('|', $myFields);?>" />
```

Comment: @yes123 - It doesn't look like a copy and paste to me.

Comment: Copy paste what ? I had the question opened in a tab and answered when I came down to it, which probably explains why I posted after you. I didn't know this site was actually a race to the first answer or that two similar opinions could not be given, and frankly you thinking I copied your answer is just silly (The first answer not edited was the same message but with a shell result rather than clear php code, I'm pretty sure mods can see my post pre-edit to confirm if need be).

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not possible. You have some other functions doing some other operations

Comment: @nick: before doing the implode do a `print_r($arr);`

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me. Try not reassigning your variables:

```
<?php 
$str = array('bob', 'john smith', 'grease monkey', 'etc');
$new_str = implode('|', $str);

echo $new_str;
?>
```